# Avoiding 'x' is not defined error while iterating over a DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I found a workaround to my problem, but I'm sure there is a much better way. I'm trying to iterate through a DataFrame, and if each index in the iteration is < 2 from the next index, then the smallest index is the key and the amount of values that are < 2 from each subsequent index are the values that are added to the new dict. Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, but in essence, if the DataFrame is:

```
      v  
1    .15  
2    .31   
3    .64   
4    .15  
7    .62   
11   .12   
15   .39   
18   .54   
19   .84
```

Then the resulting dict would be

```
{1:4, 18:2}
```

To acomplish this, I used the following code:

```
f_dict = defaultdict(int)
for id1, id2 in zip(df.iterrows(),df_test[1:].iterrows()):        
    if id2[0] - id1[0] < 2:
        f_dict[x] += 1
    else:
        x = id1[0]
```

However, when running this, as expected, I get NameError: name 'x' is not defined. Thus, by giving x a value of the first index value of the DataFrame before the iteration, it seems to solve the problem, but in a way that doesn't feel right.

```
f_dict = defaultdict(int)
x = df_test.index[0]
for id1, id2 in zip(df_test.iterrows(),df_test[1:].iterrows()):        
    if id2[0] - id1[0] < 2:
        f_dict[x] += 1
    else:
        x = id1[0]
```

This code produces the dict -

```
 {1:3, 18:1}
```

instead of

```
 {1:4, 18:2}
```

Thus, I iterate over the new dict to add 1 to each value:

```
for key in f_dict:
    f_dict[key] += 1
```

And finally I have what I'm looking for. I apologize for the improper way I'm going about solving this problem, as I'm still fairly new to python and programming in general. Is there a better way to solve this to avoid having to set x's value prior to the iteration? As well as not having to then loop over the new dict and increment each value by 1? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually sounds about right.  I'm not sure why you expected `{1:4, 18:2}` because you are really comparing the values at `(1, 2), (2, 3), (3,4)...` which you can see is only 3 counts between 1 to 4.  Also in your example you would have ended up with `{1:3, 15:1}` because `x` would not have been updated by the last iteration.

One way you can fix this is:

1. Start your default dict with `1`, because each time you counted, the # of values would be at least 2, so `f_dict[x] += 1` would always be at least 2.
2. Change your else clause to `x = df2[0]` so it uses the next index as the starting point.

---

Thus, the change would be like this:

```
f_dict = defaultdict(lambda: int(1))
x = df_test.index[0]
for id1, id2 in zip(df_test.iterrows(),df_test[1:].iterrows()):        
    if id2[0] - id1[0] < 2:
        f_dict[x] += 1
    else:
        x = id2[0]

f_dict
# {1:4, 18:2}
```

I feel like there's probably a better way to do this than `iterrows()`, but it's escaping me at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried f_dict = defaultdict(1) which obviously didn't work, but using the lambda expression to accomplish that makes much more sense. Very much appreciated.